# Spannable Text in a TextView Not Responding to Animation

Tags: android-animation, textview, spannablestring, android

I'm new at this but basically I have a textview that is fading in and out. After it fades in and out once, the text is changed.  I used a spannable string to make the first word of this text red.  When the textview with the new text is supposed to fade back in, the words that were not changed to red fade in perfectly, but the red letters do not fade in but rather appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here's the source code that should handle this in the main class:

```
     @Override

  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Red is a new message");

      text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 4, 0);  
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());        
        tv.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);  
   tv.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
  }
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I got the same problem. Thanks